# Cassandra Sample Trigger Code to get inserted value

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra

I need your help on extract column names and values in the trigger augment method.

Table Def :

```
           create table dy_data (
                                     id timeuuid,
                                     data_key text,
                                     time timestamp,
                                    data text,primary key((id,data_key),time)
                                    ) with clustering order by (time desc);
```

Trigger Code :

```
public class ArchiveTrigger implements ITrigger {
  public Collection<RowMutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily cf) {
        try {
            // Below loop only has 2 columns ( one is "data" and another one may be "time" but i am not sure, because i cannot get value.           
            for (Column cell : cf) {
                //Got Exception if I try to get column name
                String name = ByteBufferUtil.string(cell.name());
                //Got only "data" column value and empty value for another column may be "time". If I try ByteBufferUtil.toLong(cell.value()) it throws exception
                String value = ByteBufferUtil.string(cell.value());
                log(" name = " + name);
                log(" value = " + value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Exception ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried my best to search sample code in google. But failed. Please help me with sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the insert that triggers it? (I assume you are only inserting `data_key`/`data` and `time`).

Comment: No. I inserted all the data [ insert into dy_data(id,data_key,time,data) values( now(),'TX_BYTES:H',1385447412778,'data') ; ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get 'id' and 'data_key' you'll have to split the key (ByteBuffer key, the first argument to augment). 'time' will be in the first part of cell.name() - you'd still need to split it. 'data' will be the cell.value(), no need to do any splitting.

Comment: Thanks @iamaleksey for ur reply. How can I split key and how can I get first part of cell.name() ? I tried UUIDType.instance.compose(key) and it gives 'id'. But I am not able to get data_key. If I set position(16) and tried UTF8Type.instance.compose(b)). But it gives data with junk chars. And also I am not able to get 'time'. Can you please give code snippet for getting the data ? I tried many possibilities and everything failed. It would be great, if you give me code snippet to split and get 'data_key' and 'time'. Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. 'key' is of CompositeType(TimeUUIDType, UTF8Type) here, not UUIDType. And cell.name() is of CompositeType(TimestampType, UTF8Type).

Comment: Go get the type instances use the reference to the CFMetaData object in ColumnFamily (cf.metadata). The methods you should look into are getKeyValidator() and getComponentComparator(). Triggers are currently an advanced feature that requires some amount of Cassandra internals knowledge. If you don't have that, you should probably stay away from them altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks iamaleksey for you help. Your replies helps me a lot.

Below are the code snippet which will be useful for trigger users,

```
public Collection<RowMutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily cf) {
        try {
            ByteBuffer id_bb = CompositeType.extractComponent(key, 0);
            UUID id=TimeUUIDType.instance.compose(id_bb);

            ByteBuffer data_key_bb = CompositeType.extractComponent(key, 1);
            String data_key=UTF8Type.instance.compose(data_key_bb);


            Iterator col_itr=cf.iterator();

            Column ts_col=(Column)col_itr.next();
            ByteBuffer time_bb=CompositeType.extractComponent(ts_col.name(),0);
            long time=(TimestampType.instance.compose(time_bb)).getTime();


            Column data_bb=(Column)col_itr.next();
            String data=UTF8Type.instance.compose(data_bb.value());

            log(" id --> "+id.toString());
            log(" data_key-->"+data_key);
            log(" time == "+time);
            log(" data == "+data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Exception ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

PS: Since I know my table format, I hardcoded the column comparator type. If we want to write generic trigger code, we can use cf.getComponentComparator()/getKeyValidator().